# Checkbox Modification

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have a important question that I didn't find answer to, is it possible to increase the width and height of a check box and Is it possible to export to another sheet the check box with the values that were selected?

And is it possible to create multiple check boxes like for 500 or 1000 rows?

Answer (score 1):

To your **second** question..............to populate multiple CheckBoxes by rows:

```
Sub BoxMaker()
    For i = 1 To 4
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(358.5, 50, 100, 60).Select
    Next

    Dim s As Shape
    i = 2

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        s.Top = Cells(i, 1).Top
        s.Height = Cells(i, 1).Height
        s.Left = Cells(i, 1).Left
        s.Width = Cells(i, 1).Width
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

To your **first** question, just update the **.Height** and **.Width**

Comment: do you know how to put like 4 checkboxes per cell, the code is working very well and I thank you for the reply but in terms of doing this and putting 4 checkboxes per cell?

Comment: by the way If it doesn't mind you how do I change this to another cell range perhaps "H" because this is specified for the column "A"

Comment: @Luis  Use *Cells(i,8)* rather than *Cells(i,1)*

Answer (score 1):

Regarding export, link the value of the checkboxes to any cells in the sheet and export these cell values ... there are plenty of descriptions here on SO how to export cell data.

To link a checkbox to a cell use

```
Sub test()
Dim S As Shape

    Set S = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    S.ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "B1"

End Sub
```

To add this to Gary's Student's code ...

```
Sub BoxMaker()
    For i = 1 To 4
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(358.5, 50, 100, 60).Select
    Next

    Dim s As Shape
    i = 2

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        s.Top = Cells(i, 1).Top
        s.Height = Cells(i, 1).Height
        s.Left = Cells(i, 1).Left
        s.Width = Cells(i, 1).Width

        ' add Cell Link
        ' 2nd parameter of Cells(i, 2).Address sets column of linked cell ... in this case column B
        s.ControlFormat.LinkedCell = Cells(i, 2).Address

        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

fields will be filled after first click to the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, put how do I put this to make the value appear in multiple rows? like B1 to B500 and could you just explain what is the "Shapes(1)"?

Comment: Shapes(1) references the first shape you created ... just an example to demonstrate the use of `.ControlFormat.LinkedCell` ... see edit ... I inserted this code in to the routine of @Gary